# set soapaction header in a java client

Tags: java

i have created a java client in netbeans 7.2 from a wsdl
the issue is that the header send Soapaction but the server is expecting to receive SOAPAction

i try to overwrite the properties using this code

```
    BindingProvider prov = (BindingProvider)port;
    prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.SOAPACTION_USE_PROPERTY, false);
    prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.SOAPACTION_URI_PROPERTY, "http://www.microsoft.com");
```

but again in the server it receives Soapaction instead of receiving SOAPAction

can someone tell me how can i overright this value?

thank you

Comment: what is the error you received from the server, add the stacktrace pls

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to add it in a wrong place.

BindingProvider is only the stub object, "provides access to the protocol binding and associated context objects for request and response message processing."

What you really need here is an SOAP message interceptor, which you can use to customize your SOAP messages generated by your WS library.

In case you use JAX-WS, you can use for example SOAPHandlers to do this.

Here is an example:
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-soap-handler-in-client-side/

If this is not your case, please provide more details about your application (what kind of project it is, what kind of WS implementation you are using etc).

Comment: HI , i'm using netbenas 7.2 webapplication project. the JAX-WS is the following   
/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.2.6-1b01 
 * Generated source version: 2.2
 * 
 */   i have seen the article but i didn't see how to overright the soapaction properties and how to use the custom class, can you help me out on this? thank you

Comment: You can add custom elements in the handleMessage() method of the SOAPHandler. I think you should add a header element as MimeHeader, like here: http://www.herongyang.com/Web-Services/SAAJ-addHeader-Set-SOAPAction-Header-Line.html

Comment: ok but in my case how can i add the header. the problem is that in my case i don't have any object where to set up the header. in the example you post there is the creation of a soap message but in my case i have already a soap message and i don't know how to manage the properties

Comment: You should add a SOAPHandler class to your codebase, and add the header in the handleMessage() method, so you should combine the two sources I mentioned.

Here is a sample: http://pastebin.com/RBmFKvCb

Comment: thanks gabosky for your answer and your time but i need your help. this is the java code created by netbeans     private static OrderResponse customerOrderAdd(fluidra_b2b_customerorder.Order parameters) {
        net.fluidra.ws.b2b.B2B_Service service = new net.fluidra.ws.b2b.B2B_Service();
        net.fluidra.ws.b2b.B2B port = service.getB2BSOAP();
//        WSBindingProvider bp  = (WSBindingProvider)port;
//        bp.setOutboundHeaders(Headers.create(new QName("SOAPAction"),"SOAPAction"));
        // Basic Authentication
        
    
        return port.customerOrderAdd(parameters);
    }

Comment: this is the call         try{
        
            or = customerOrderAdd(o);
            
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            ex = e.getMessage();
            ex = ex + " ";
        }
so how can i use the custom handler you told me in my case? thanks

Comment: Please read through the original article I posted in my original answer. You should specify the SOAPHandler in a handler-chain.xml file.

Comment: gabo, in the original article there are 2 SOAPHandler, one for server one for client. btw the client class that invoke the webservice has no code about the handler itsellf. this means that the handler is called automatically before send the message?????

Comment: In the article there is only one SOAPHandler, called MacAddressInjectHandler. It works with as an interceptor, so yes, it is called automatically for every message sent/received so you can transform these. The SOAPHandler is configured via the xml, and this xml should be specified in your WSClient as @HandlerChain(file="handler-chain.xml").

Comment: gabo, this is how to add a property in the soap header //add a soap header, name as "mac address"
            QName qname = new QName("http://ws.mkyong.com/", "macAddress");
            SOAPHeaderElement soapHeaderElement = soapHeader.addHeaderElement(qname);

            soapHeaderElement.setActor(SOAPConstants.URI_SOAP_ACTOR_NEXT);
            soapHeaderElement.addTextNode(mac);
            soapMsg.saveChanges();                                                            but what about replace one property? i mean, i need to overright the property Soapaction with SOAPAction. it is possible?

Comment: well, I think you have no other choice but to remove the wrong header and add a correct one, like this for example: http://pastebin.com/q89wDdpy

Comment: thank you gabo, that is what i need, i will try and i will let you know

Comment: I am glad if I could provide an idea how to solve the problem. Please let me know if you have any more questions